# Raw Socket Python Application deployed httpd

Tags: python, apache, raw-sockets

I have an python flask application that deployed httpd.
And in this application, I am sending syn packet and calculating response time.
I am using scapy to send syn packet.

So Issue is;

Scapy uses raw socket to send packet but raw socket can open by root user :(
So, httpd run as other user and raises exception that "Operation not permitted".

I already tried that,

```
setcap cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw=eip /usr/sbin/httpd
```

But still raises exception that 'Operation not permitted'

Best regards..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using that what you can do is just open up Command line if your on windows as admin and then run the script and it should work fine